# Uploading a file in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

When I try to upload a file I get this error

> app.component.ts:26          POST http://localhost:3000/uploadFile net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import {  HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule, // required for input file change detection
ReactiveFormsModule,
HttpClientModule, // this is required for the actual http request
  ],
  providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })

  export class AppModule { }
```

This is upload `service.ts`:

```
import { UploadService } from './upload.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 
 file: File = null;
 
 constructor(
   private uploadService: UploadService
 ){
 
 }
 
 onFilechange(event: any) {
   console.log(event.target.files[0])
   this.file = event.target.files[0]
 }
 
 upload() {
   if (this.file) {
     this.uploadService.uploadfile(this.file).subscribe(resp => {
       alert("Uploaded")
     })
   } else {
     alert("Please select a file first")
   }
 }
}
```

This is `app.component.html`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Upload file example</label>
        <input (change)="this.onFilechange($event)" class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
        <button (click)="this.upload()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And this is my `upload-service.ts`:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {

 constructor(
  private httpClient: HttpClient,
 ) { }

public uploadfile(file: File) {
  let formParams = new FormData();
  formParams.append('file', file)
  return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/uploadFile', formParams)
}
```

Comment: let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); |  Not sure if this is the solution, buy try that code. Remember to pass the options  return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/uploadFile', formParams, options)

Comment: hello thank you i tried this code but i got this error Cannot find name 'RequestOptions'.ts(2304)